# Trying to check my Python packages but keeps telling me that aiohttp is not installed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to check what packages are installed in my virtual environments, I have different packages from different virtual environments depends on what project I am working on. Whatever virtual environment I switch I always get this error when using `help("modules")`

```
aiohttp dependency is not installed: No module named 'aiohttp'. Please re-install black with the '[d]' extra install to obtain aiohttp_cors: `pip install black[d]`
```

My question is how do I install this package correctly, and by that I mean should I install it in my main Python PATH? I'm not sure if this is a mandatory package that I need it installed in my main environment if that makes sense.

My Python version is **`3.9.6`** by the way.

EDIT: I was able to fetch all of my packages.

I had to do a `. Scripts/activate` first, but it was weird because before I did not have to do the activate command before, since VS Code displays on the lower left portion of the screen what environment you are currently using, I'm not sure if I had any settings change prior to this bug.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to open new terminal

Comment: This works. I have bash set as my terminal in VS Code, but when I restart my VS code, the environment I prefer is not automatically set. Need to reopen a new terminal for the environment to be set.